# React Modal selected data dissapears after it closes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following problem my selected option dissapears after i close and reopen modal , someone told me this is because all data gets lost when a modal unmounts? So how do i cause the selected data to still show.

I am able to retrieve the selected data but all i want is the selected option to still be there once modal closes and reopens

Also My select component is not reusable any clue how i could optimize that piece of code

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';
import Button from '../Button/Button'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  modal: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

 const TransitionsModal =(props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button clicked={handleOpen}></Button>

      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
{props.children}
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
export default TransitionsModal
```

Here is my select component

```
import React from 'react';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

export default function NativeSelects(props) {

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = event => {

    setValue(event.target.value);
    console.log(event.target.value)
  };


  const data = props.list.map((item, id) => {
    if (item.reciter_name_eng) {

      return <option key={item.reciter_name_eng + id} value={item.id}>{item.reciter_name_eng} {item.style}</option>
    }
    //if its not null 
    if (item.name_simple) {
      return <option key={item.name_simple + id} value={item.chapter_number}>{item.chapter_number}. {item.name_simple}</option>
    }
    if (item.language_name) {
      return <option key={item.language_name + id} value={item.id}>{item.language_name} by {item.author_name}</option>
    }
    return null

  })

  return (

    <div>
      <FormControl variant="filled">
        <InputLabel htmlFor="filled-age-native-simple">{props.type}</InputLabel>
        <Select
          native
          value={value}
          onChange={(event) => { props.changed(event.target.value, props.type); handleChange(event) }}>
          <option value={null}> </option>
          }
   {data}

        </Select>
      </FormControl>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://gyazo.com/5dd496ac363760f16f3f82901acfd40e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the default state of your Function Component is always an empty string i.e

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
```

When the modal is closed, the components are all unmounted, meaning when the modal is then reshown these are remounted and as a result the value will go back to an empty string.

You need to keep track of the selected value `TransitionModel` component and then pass this back into `NativeSelects` as a prop in order to set the default value  i.e.

```
<NativeSelect defaultValue={...} />
```

Then in your component

```
function NativeSelect(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(props.defaultValue);
  ...
}
```